# Magento- Country Specific Payment Option is not showing on One Page Checkout

Tags: magento

I have COD set for a specific country and it doesn't shows up in OPC for the first time. It only appears after a full reload of the checkout page or if the customer is logged in.
Once the billing information is filled up the Ajax is called but the payment option fails to show up.

**I guess its a theme problem. So, what to do now? Is there any fix?

Comment: its not a theme problem. have you enabled guest checkout ?

Comment: 1. Yes Guest Checkout is enabled.
2. It only appears after a full page reload. Guess the ajax call is not working.
3. Second payment option which is not country specific is shown all along.

If you need any other info then please let me know.

Comment: if guest checkout is enable then magento not able to check the country for guest user unless he is login. try without guest user. and if still there is a issue then try to use default theme for the same.

Comment: Yes magento cannot check the country for the guest checkout. So what to do now?
Cannot disable the guest checkout and cannot throw away the theme because its a paid theme.

Is there any other way to get it fixed?

Comment: on which magneto version you are working?